# np.std in python from weighted samples coming out different from theoretical?

Tags: python, numpy

I am sampling from three distributions with a set weight and i'm cross checking that the sampling is working as intended. I have some checks at the end of this code to check that the expected mean (weight * mean of each distribution) is the same, which it is, and that the standard deviation is also the same. However, I can't seem to get the standard deviation to match up? I'm not sure why, as I think the sampling is working as intended, but need help figuring out why std_generated and expected_std are different

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import expon
np.random.seed(42)  # Set a specific seed value


# Assuming disbn_1, disbn_2, and disbn_3 are your frozen distribution objects
# and w_1, w_2, w_3 are the corresponding probabilities

# Set up your distribution objects
par_1 = 2.0  # Adjust this parameter according to your specific distribution
disbn_1 = expon(scale=par_1)
disbn_2 = expon(scale=1.0)  # Adjust parameters as needed
disbn_3 = expon(scale=0.5)  # Adjust parameters as needed

# Set up probabilities
w_1, w_2, w_3 = 0.4, 0.3, 0.3
weights = np.array([w_1, w_2, w_3])

# Number of samples you want to generate
num_samples = 5000000  # Increase the number of samples

# Sample from the distributions with specified probabilities
selected_distributions = [disbn_1, disbn_2, disbn_3]
random_indices = np.random.choice(len(weights), size=num_samples, p=weights)

# Use np.choose to select samples based on random indices
selected_samples = np.choose(random_indices, [dist.rvs(size=num_samples) for dist in selected_distributions])

# Calculate summary statistics
mean_generated = np.mean(selected_samples)
std_generated = np.std(selected_samples,ddof=0) 

# Calculate expected mean and std based on the specified distribution and probabilities
expected_mean = np.sum(weights * np.array([dist.mean() for dist in selected_distributions]))
expected_std = np.sqrt(np.sum(weights * np.array([dist.var() for dist in selected_distributions])))

# Display results
print(f"Mean of generated samples: {mean_generated:.6f}")
print(f"Expected mean based on distribution: {expected_mean:.6f}")
print()
print(f"Standard deviation of generated samples: {std_generated:.6f}")
print(f"Expected standard deviation based on distribution: {expected_std:.6f}")
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you're calculating the standard deviation does not take into account different means between distributions.

Here's an example.

Suppose you have two normal distributions, N(0, 1) and N(10, 1). You sample from each of these distributions with equal probability to create a sample.

[image: graph of bimodal sample from two normal distribution]

If you apply your formula to this sample, you have sqrt(0.5 * var(dist1) + 0.5 * var(dist2)), which equals 1. However, the real standard deviation is a little bit more than 5. So, clearly there's a missing piece here.

So, I went looking for a way to get the standard deviation of a sample, knowing the standard deviation and means of its component distributions.

I found the following MathOverflow post. [How do I combine standard deviations of two groups?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2971315/how-do-i-combine-standard-deviations-of-two-groups)

This answer is for 2 groups, but with a little bit of work, we can adapt it to work for an arbitrary number of groups.

```
def combined_std(means, stds, samples_per_dist):
    means = np.array(means)
    stds = np.array(stds)
    samples_per_dist = np.array(samples_per_dist)
    assert means.shape == stds.shape == samples_per_dist.shape
    proportions = samples_per_dist / samples_per_dist.sum()
    combined_mean = np.average(means, weights=proportions)
    intra_distribution_var = ((samples_per_dist - 1) * (stds ** 2)).sum() / (samples_per_dist.sum() - 1)
    inter_distribution_var = (samples_per_dist * ((means - combined_mean) ** 2)).sum() / (samples_per_dist.sum() - 1)
    combined_var = intra_distribution_var + inter_distribution_var
    combined_std = np.sqrt(combined_var)
    return combined_std
```

This function is called like this:

```
means = [dist.mean() for dist in selected_distributions]
stds = [dist.std() for dist in selected_distributions]
samples_per_dist = num_samples * weights
expected_std = combined_std(means, stds, samples_per_dist)
```

The inter_distribution_var term corrects for differences in mean between distributions.

Applying it to your distributions, I get an expected standard deviation of 1.545154, which is fairly close to your experimental result.